# Open expansion panels on their creation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Within my application, I have a section containing multiple different expansion panels with each being a separate component. Depending on user input different expansion panels should be shown. It is important that this is done using v-if as opposed to v-show.

I have created the following codepen of a simplified example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-leaf-rne03?file=/src/main.js

The issue I am having is I wish for the panels to be open when they are created. As can be seen in my example, the first created panel is open. However, after hiding and then showing again, the panel is closed. How could I set the expansion panels as being open each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the `panel` variable becomes an empty array `[]` when the `<v-expansion-panel/>` is removed from the DOM. So when you bring back the `</v-expansion-panel/>`, there are no opened panels.

But, what you can do is to [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) the `panel` variable and prevent it from having an empty array. Something like this:

```js
data() {return {...}},
watch: {
  panel(newVal) {
    // Check if the expansion panels are not showing.
    if (!(newVal && newVal.length) && !this.showPanel) {
      this.panel = [0]; // back to default if newVal is empty
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-shape-b9hg3?file=/src/App.vue:548-699).

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I was just testing this and although the panel is now being displayed in the open state, I realised that you are not able to toggle it to be open/closed by clicking on the header which is very interesting! Any suggestions as to why that might be?

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that. In that case, let's check if `showPanel` is false before setting back the `panel` to `[0]` (the default value). See my latest edit. I also updated the demo at codesandbox as well so you can try it.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Thanks so much

Comment: No problem. Goodluck!